# Use cases OutputStream(java.io) vs Channel(java.nio)

Tags: java, java-io, java-nio

Did i right understand, what Channel used for cases, when data, which we want to write - is not full received/prepared data?

But OutputStream used for case when we can write all data already now.

Another words:
nio - when we asynchronous getting data for writing
io - when we synchronous got data for writing

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no such a type as `java.io.Stream`;
2. If you, by any means, meant `java.util.Stream` and `java.nio.channels.Channels`, then they are two completely different types serving different purposes;
3. Finally, if you are comparing `java.io` and `java.nio`, then `io` is about reading and writing, whereas `nio` is about faster I/O, a.k.a buffered-reading and buffered-writing operations.